# Exporting single-sided from LyX

Tags: lyx

I'm trying to convert the LyX documentation to PDFs to read on a tablet. Some of the LyX documentation, though, is set to double-sided which of course a table isn't.

It'd *seem* `buffer-params-apply \papersides 1` ought to do that. I'm testing on `Customization.lyx`, and if I run that in the GUI (after `buffer-toggle-read-only` to make the buffer editable), it seems to set it to single-sided... but also toss the rest of the document settings. I ran it with `-dbg action`, and the amount of stuff hitting "apply" in the document settings dialog passes to that function is ridiculous.

If I try it on the command line:

```bash
lyx -x 'buffer-toggle-read-only' -x 'buffer-params-apply \papersides 1' \
    -E pdf2 '/tmp/LyX/Customization.pdf' 'Customization.lyx'
```

... then it seems to just do nothing (I tried both with and without buffer-toggle-read-only). That is, no errors are produced (even with adding `-dbg action`) and the generated PDF is still double-sided.

LyX does its best to complicate simple solutions using `sed` as well:

```
$ lyx  -E pdf2 /tmp/LyX/Customization.pdf <(sed -e 's!^\\papersides 2$!\\papersides 1!' Customization.lyx )
LyX failed to load the following file: /dev/fd/63.lyx
```

I got `sed` to work with a tempfile, but it seems really hard to believe there isn't an easy way to override single/double-sided when exporting to PDF. What did I miss?

(This is LyX 2.3.2, running on Debian Buster)

Comment: @KJO Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do, but automatically when exporting, not manually by opening LyX and saving a new copy of the document.

Comment: @KJO My apologies if I've posted an off-topic question, but I'm confused as LyX is listed as on-topic in https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic ("Related software and tools, BibTeX, MakeIndex, Lyx, etc.") Checking meta I couldn't find anything to the contrary either.

Answer (score 1):

Taking this on as a TeX related task

In LyX files, double page spread is simply stored as:-

```
\papersides = 2
```

When converted to TeX using:-

```
lyx --force-overwrite --export pdflatex doublepage.lyx
```

such documentation files will default to 2 sided with a third line of:-

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,german,french,english,bibliography=totoc,index=totoc,BCOR7.5mm,titlepage,captions=tableheading]{scrbook}
```

What LyX would do is to inject `oneside,` between `12pt,` and `fleqn,` and rename to oneside.tex

Then you can attempt `PdfLaTeX oneside.tex`. However be warned in testing this approach there are many undesirable warnings about old Latex constructs like the visible BCOR7.5mm (should be changed to lowercase with = i.e. bcor=7.5mm). Also it may be worth waiting this week for the new 2.3.3 release to see if anything improves.