# Is there a program to convert .docx or .odt to .tex

Tags: conversion

I am trying to find a way for a user to design and modify pages without requiring him to learn LaTeX. The pages have graphical elements in the form of rounded rectangles to denote regions of a page, such as a "Ship To" address, etc., and embedded graphics such as a company logo.

The reason I want to produce LaTeX output is because, once the form has been designed, I need to print it and/or produce a PDF version under program control (on a Linux box, so probably python).

I have...

- tried the Writer2LaTeX extension for LibreOffice but it ignores "Draw" elements, which is what a rounded rectangle is
- looked at python-docx package but that seems to be more oriented to creating and modifying a Word document rather than extracting stuff from one
- looked at LyX but it doesn't allow me to create "Draw" objects

I should also note that I am brand-new to LaTeX so may not be aware of the full capabilities of LaTeX and the various packages available, so I am completely open to just about any other ideas.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Design the form in Word, and then produce a LaTeX document class based on that design once it's finalized. Trying to do this by an automatic conversion process is very unlikely to work.

Comment: You could try pandoc, but like Alan I doubt that something graphical orientated will really work well.

Comment: A think that this question is a duplicate of this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27731/how-can-i-convert-from-microsoft-word-to-a-latex-document. However there is a program not-free that convert from Word to LaTeX. I don't know if I can write it here.

Comment: Tried pandoc with a super simple .odt consisting of two rounded rectangles with enclosed text boxes (and text in them, of course). Got an empty \begin{document} section. :-/

Comment: @Sebastiano, can you PM me the name? Thanks. I'm open to looking at it at least.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry to bother you. Can I write the name of the program I know? hi and thank you.

Comment: @Sebastiano There is no prohibition on mentioning commercial software. There's a prohibition on advertising, but that's not what you would be doing.

Comment: @AlanMunn Absolutely not. I mention only the program called GrindEQ.

Comment: @ColinWu See the name of the software into the last my comment for AlanMunn.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Like [Ulrike](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) said you can try [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/). I have used it for simple conversions, but nothing with the graphics boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Too graphic for a comment. Note it is possible for simple users like me to create such graphics using LyX 2.3.3 to compile the TeX without using the included python !

[image]

Hints for programmed TeXport can be found here [Exporting single-sided from LyX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497420/exporting-single-sided-from-lyx) and [Transfer .tex file from LyX into LaTeXmk](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496459/transfer-tex-file-from-lyx-into-latexmk)

Comment: Guess I had better give LyX another look. I confess my previous peek was pretty superficial. Also, the version I looked at was v 2.3.2.

Comment: no it is not. I am now leaning towards writing my own translator (for the subset of ODT elements that I need) to create a template.